# Laravel eloquent Scope AND

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 1 table postad with fields (title,cat1,cat2,cat3,cat4,location,city,area)

Now I am passing 2 values category_id and location searching results from post ad table .

Here is my code
// Search for category,location

```
public function scopeLocationSearch($query,$post_location,$category_id) 
{
    return $query->category($category_id)->location($post_location)->get();     
}
```

category and location scopes are Scopes are as follows:

```
public function scopeCategory($query,$cat_id)
{
    return $query->where('cat1', $cat_id)
                 ->orWhere('cat2', $cat_id)
                 ->orWhere('cat3', $cat_id)
                 ->orWhere('cat4', $cat_id);
}

public function scopeLocation($query,$location)
{
    return $query->where('location','LIKE','%'.$location.'%')
                 ->orWhere('city','LIKE', '%'.$location.'%')
                 ->orWhere('area','LIKE', '%'.$location.'%');
}
```

Individually these scopes are giving results what I want but when I am calling locationsearch , it giving wrong results. It is just providing me `OR` results but I want `AND` results.

Thanks

Comment: Instead of `->orWhere(...)` just use another `->where(...)`. Laravel will use `AND` comparator.

Comment: there are 2 groups like category and location, there is (or between all categories) and (or between all locations)

Comment: I see now. Try this in your scopeLocationSearch: `$query->where(function($q){ $q->location(...);})->where(function($q){ $q->category(...)});`

Comment: tried $query->where(function($q,$post_location){ $q->location($post_location);})->where(function($q,$category_id){$q->category($category_id);});   but getting error now Missing argument 2 for App\PostAd::App\{closure}()

Answer (score 1):

When you use `or` operator for conditions, you should wrap whole condition into closure to make sure valid query will be executed.

Your methods should look like so:

```
public function scopeCategory($query,$cat_id)
{
    return $query->where(function($query) use ($cat_id) {
                  $query->where('cat1', $cat_id)
                 ->orWhere('cat2', $cat_id)
                 ->orWhere('cat3', $cat_id)
                 ->orWhere('cat4', $cat_id);
                 });
}

public function scopeLocation($query,$location)
{
    return $query->where(function($query) use ($location) {
                  $query->where('location','LIKE','%'.$location.'%')
                 ->orWhere('city','LIKE', '%'.$location.'%')
                 ->orWhere('area','LIKE', '%'.$location.'%');
           });
}
```